# Set cursor to be <symbol> element

Tags: javascript, html, css, mouse-cursor

I have an HTML symbol

```
<symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 8.4666659 8.4666659">
  <g transform="translate(0,-288.53334)">
    <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.48417112;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;" d="m 0.17215798,288.70836 8.05225192,8.04935"></path>
    <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.48417112;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;" d="m 8.2221335,293.64243 0.00228,3.11528 -3.1283502,2.2e-4"></path>
  </g>
</symbol>
```

which I want to use as the cursor. I'm familiar with changing the cursor via JQuery like this:

```
body.css('cursor', `wait`);
```

But how can I do this for a `<symbol>` element?

Comment: Relevant CSS-Tricks article: https://css-tricks.com/using-css-cursors/#article-header-id-1 Unfortunately, looks like their demo of using an SVG (albeit an CSS/base64-encoded one) doesn't work on my Chrome for macOS. But you could copy their JS demo of using a custom element as a "cursor" to follow the mouse.

Comment: Doesn't seem to work for SVG in Chrome on Windows either...

Comment: I'm looking around for verification of this but can't find anything.. appears SVG and GIF support for custom cursors in Chrome is broken.. tried stable and dev channels.  Safari likes SVG, but not base64 SVG or GIF... https://codepen.io/geoffgraham/pen/QNgoQW

Comment: Alright, so here's my stab at it. Disclaimer: This is a work in progress. Only working on Windows in Chrome,FF,Opera. Doesn't work in IE/Edge. Had to add an xmlns namespace to the element as well as change it from an <sybmol> to an <svg> element. https://jsfiddle.net/6jnvcsu4/56/  Is this even remotely close to what you're trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 18):

You can set two `<svg>` elements one to define your SVG symbol and the other to hold the element. Then with Javascript, you can set an event listener and change the position of the whole `<svg>` (the one holding your element) when the user's cursor moves. Also, I have hidden the default browser cursor with the CSS property `cursor: none`. Here's a working code:

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  let newTransformRule = 'translate(' + (e.pageX - 360) + 'px, ' + (e.pageY - 115) + 'px)';

  document.querySelector('#arrowCanvas').style.transform = newTransformRule;

});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<svg>
  <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 8.4666659 8.4666659">
    <g transform="translate(0,-288.53334)">
      <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.48417112;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;" d="m 0.17215798,288.70836 8.05225192,8.04935"></path>
      <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.48417112;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;" d="m 8.2221335,293.64243 0.00228,3.11528 -3.1283502,2.2e-4"></path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg id="arrowCanvas" width="100" height="60">
  <use href="#arrow" width="100" height="50"/>
</svg>
```

You will have to tweak the values in `newTransformRule` to center your custom cursor with the default cursor. Remove the CSS rule to do the adjustment.

The code is working on Firefox, Chrome and Edge.

Answer (score 0):

@Ivan answer is good, but, this way it will work better.

I just made some changes

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {

  let newTransformRule = 'translate(' + (e.pageX - 380) + 'px, ' + (e.pageY - 60) + 'px)';

  document.querySelector('#arrowCanvas').style.transform = newTransformRule;

});
```

```css
body {
  cursor: none;
}

#arrowCanvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<svg id="arrowContainer">
  <symbol id="arrow" viewBox="0 0 8.4666659 8.4666659">
    <g transform="translate(0,-288.53334)">
      <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.48417112;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;" d="m 0.17215798,288.70836 8.05225192,8.04935"></path>
      <path style="fill:none;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:0.48417112;stroke-linecap:butt;stroke-linejoin:miter;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-dasharray:none;stroke-opacity:1;" d="m 8.2221335,293.64243 0.00228,3.11528 -3.1283502,2.2e-4"></path>
    </g>
  </symbol>
</svg>

<svg id="arrowCanvas" width="100" height="60">
  <use href="#arrow" width="100" height="50"/>
</svg>
```