# How to change cursor on multiple mouseovers

Tags: javascript, css, image, cursor, mouseover

I am trying to change my cursor into different images depending on the object that it is hovering over inside my banner. Currently I only know to change the cursor style in CSS. But the cursor stays the same throughout. How do I replace the cursor image on mouseover in my javascript? I am only using jQuery and TweenMax as this is for an assignment.

Comment: You might want to post a bit of code here so we can help you.

Comment: css is the correct way. My guess is you haven't set up rules for `:hover` Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: Show your code.

Comment: Please let me know if my answer helped you solve your problem.

Answer (score 2):

### Using CSS `cursor` property

Without using any pseudo-selectors in CSS, you can have a pretty good result by playing around with the `cursor` property. For example, you can select one cursor style from a range of [available ones](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp). Or even add your own by linking the URL of the icon.

For example, the code below will show a heart when you hover over the grey area:

```css
.heart {
  cursor: url("https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/9632/heart.png"), auto;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="heart"></div>
```

You can change the origin of the image's position relative to the actual mouse position by setting the `x` and `y` position along with the URL in the `cursor` property:

```
cursor: url(<URL>) [x y|auto];
```

---

### Using JavaScript

Of course, you can handle this feature with JavaScript code. Here are several things we will need to achieve this:

- creating an HTML element with the image of the cursor you want as background
- using the [`onmouseenter`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseenter.asp), [`onmousemove`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmousemove.asp) and [`onmouseleave`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onmouseleave.asp) events
- getting the position of the mouse on the page: properties [`pageX`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageX), [`pageY`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/pageY)
- setting the position of our `cursor` element to be at the position of the mouse (the actual mouse pointer will be hidden): with the [`transform`](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_transform.asp) CSS property.

There are several other tricks I have used to get it right: for example setting the boxes' overflow to be `hidden` so that the `cursor` elements can't be seen outside the box. Also, listening to the `onmouseleave` event allows us to hide the `cursor` element when the mouse is outside the box area.

I have made a little demo here, click <kbd>Show code snippet</kbd> > <kbd>Run code snippet</kbd>:

```js
const showCursor = function(event) {
  let cursor = event.target.querySelector('.cursor');
  
  event.target.onmousemove = function(e) {
    cursor.style.display = 'block'
    let [x, y] = [e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft - 20, e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop - 20]
    cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`
  }

  event.target.onmouseleave = function(e) {
    cursor.style.display = 'none'
  }

}
```

```css
.box {
  cursor: none;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  background: pink;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 10px;
}

.box:nth-child(1) {
  background: aquamarine;
}

.box:nth-child(2) {
  background: pink;
}

.box:nth-child(3) {
  background: cornflowerblue;
}

.box:nth-child(4) {
  background: lightcoral;
}

.cursor {
  display: none;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

#heart {
  background: no-repeat url("https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/hearts.png");
}

#diamond {
  background: no-repeat url("https://png.icons8.com/color/50/000000/diamonds.png")
}

#spade {
  background: no-repeat url("https://png.icons8.com/metro/50/000000/spades.png")
}

#clubs {
  background: no-repeat url("https://png.icons8.com/ios/50/000000/clubs-filled.png")
}
```

```html
<div onmousemove="showCursor(event)" class="box">
  <div id="diamond" class="cursor"></div>
</div>
<div onmouseenter="showCursor(event)" class="box">
  <div id="heart" class="cursor"></div>
</div>

<div onmousemove="showCursor(event)" class="box">
  <div id="spade" class="cursor"></div>
</div>
<div onmousemove="showCursor(event)" class="box">
  <div id="clubs" class="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

The function `showCursor()` is called when the user's mouse enters one of the boxes with the attribute `onmouseenter="showCursor(event)"` (see HTML markup above).

Below I have provided the JavaScript code *with comments* explaining how it works:

```js
const showCursor = function(event) {
  // get the element object of the cursor of this box
  let cursor = event.target.querySelector('.cursor');

  // function that will be execute whenever the user moves inside the box
  event.target.onmousemove = function(e) {
    // the user is moving inside the box

    // show the cursor element
    cursor.style.display = 'block'

    // calcultate the translate values of the cursor element
    let [x, y] = [e.pageX - e.target.offsetLeft - 20, e.pageY - e.target.offsetTop - 20]

    // apply these values to the style of the cursor element
    cursor.style.transform = `translate(${x}px, ${y}px)`

  }

  // function that will be executed when the user leaves the box 
  event.target.onmouseleave = function(e) {
    // the user's mouse left the box area

    // hide the cursor element
    cursor.style.display = 'none'
  }

}
```

---

### With a `<svg>` element

A while ago I answered a post on [how to add an `<svg>` element as the cursor](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45943033/6331369) of the mouse. It's a little bit more advanced though. It's still a JavaScript solution but it involves using a `<svg>` element as the `cursor` instead of it being a simple `<div>` (as seen in the second point).